# Is it unpythonic to use a package imported by another package, or should I import it directly?

Tags: python, import

For instance, I want to use `numpy`'s `isnan` function. I've already loaded the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.np.isnan(1) #=> False
```

That works, but is there any disadvantage to that? Or should I write

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.isnan(1) #=> False
```

What is good practice?

Comment: I think this actually does have a fact-based answer, covered in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces), and should be reopened.

Comment: In short: `np` is not documented in `help(pd)` or Pandas' web-based help, and "All undocumented interfaces should be assumed to be internal." The fact that Pandas doesn't have an `__all__` that excludes `np` or `import numpy as _np` is less than ideal (although not to the extend that I'd call it a bug), but it still doesn't mean that accidentally exposed names that aren't documented are part of the public interface.

Comment: Besides what's already been said, there is no performance impact to reimporting `numpy`, as Python caches imports.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I doubt he's worried about performance impact. Any program where the slowest thing is importing `numpy` is unlikely to need to be performance-optimized in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: You never know who's worried about what, and more than just OP will read these comments.  :)

Comment: @EthanFurman: Well, I doubt _anyone's_ worried about performance impact for any good reason. Seriously, what kind of program can you imagine where the 0.05s to (re-)import numpy would matter, given that pandas import takes about 6 times as long, and that you must actually be _doing_ something with pandas or the obvious optimization would be to not import it?

Comment: Definitely the second. If you want `numpy`, import and use. Whether some other package is using it or not is not something you can rely on. Anything could change in their internal API and your code will break.

Comment: Simple test: if you look at "np.isnan", how hard is it for someone who doesn't intricately know what that's supposed to mean (that is, *you* and only in the few minutes to maybe hours after you wrote it…) to find out what it *does* mean?

If you instead import numpy (even as "np") explicitly in your code, and then use that, a quick search in your source gives the answer.

That's why everyone here recommends to explicitly import every package/module you use directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the second approach for at least four reasons:

1. As @abarnert said in the comments, it follows the official guidelines for Python code as stated in PEP 0008 under [Public and internal interfaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces).  Specifically, the PEP says:

   > All undocumented interfaces should be assumed to be internal.

   and:

   > Imported names should always be considered an implementation detail.
   >   Other modules must not rely on indirect access to such imported names
   >   unless they are an explicitly documented part of the containing
   >   module's API, such as `os.path` or a package's`__init__` module that
   >   exposes functionality from submodules.

   Because NumPy is an undocumented aspect of the Pandas library (it is not mentioned in either  `help(pd)` nor on the official website), it should not be  considered as an official part of Pandas.
2. ["Explicit is better than implicit"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and the second approach makes it explicit that we are using the NumPy library directly in the code.  The first approach however kinda "slips it in" through the Pandas library.
3. Code analysis tools will be unable to see that your code is using NumPy directly.  This could generate false data concerning your code (such as what dependencies it has).
4. The fact that Pandas contains NumPy is nothing more than an implementation detail. Meaning, should the makers of Pandas ever change their internal code to alter this detail in any way, all of your Numpy code could suddenly break when it really shouldn't.  Numpy and Pandas are two separate things and should be treated as such.

Comment: I'm not sure about #3; I'm pretty sure some Pandas methods are documented to explicitly return and/or take NumPy arrays, and the fact that Pandas is built on NumPy is something I think pretty much everyone assumes. (However, that _doesn't_ imply that Pandas has to export `numpy` as `np`, of course, which gets back to the first two answers.)

Comment: I was just moving that from my comment into my answer.  I don't use Pandas a whole lot so I only know the basics about it.  I'll change the wording to be less strict.